# In Javascript, How to sum up all the values in an array from a drop down list and form?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to create an online order menu, and when user clicks "Add Side Dish" button, it will display the side dish name added in an unordered list, but also at the same time, I want to add the cost (defined in value), to an array where I can later click calculate to add the cost of the main dish selected, and the cost of all the added side dish to get the total for the order.

I've tried to add the cost of the side dish into an array, then convert it into a string, and then add the main dish cost and the side dish cost together but I didn't have any luck.

HTML

```
    <select id="mainDish">
            <option value="15"></option>
            <option value="13"></option>
            <option value="17"></option>
        </select>
    </p><br>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 300px;">
        <p>Select Your Side Dishes</p>
            <p>Side Dishes
                <select id="sideDish">
                    <option value="2"></option>
                    <option value="5"></option>
                    <option value="6"></option>
                    <option value="5"></option>
                </select>
            </p>
        <button id="addSideDish"></button>
        <button id="removeSideDish"></button>
        <p>Current Side Dishes</p>
        <ul id="list">
            
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button id="total">Calculate Cost</button>
    <h2>Total Cost:</h2>
    <p id="totalCost"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
let main = document.getElementById("mainDish");
let side = document.getElementById("sideDish");
let ul = document.getElementById("list");
let li = document.createElement("li");
let rice = document.getElementById("rice");
let naan = document.getElementById("naan");
let sideDishes = [];

function addSideDish(){
    let sideValue = side.value;
    sideDishes.push(sideValue);
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<li>"+sideDishes[sideDishes.length-1]+"</li>";
}

function removeSideDish(){
    
}

function calculate(){
    let sideValue = side.value;
    let sum;
    sideDishes.forEach(function(entry) {
        sideDishes.push(entry);
        console.log(entry);
        console.log(sideDishes);
    let mainValue = main.value;
    let sideString = parseFloat(sideDishes);
    let mainString = parseFloat(mainValue);
    let entryString = parseFloat(entry);
    let add = entryString + mainString;
    document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML = add;
    }); 
}
document.getElementById("addSideDish").onclick = addSideDish;
document.getElementById("removeSideDish").onclick = removeSideDish;
document.getElementById("total").onclick = calculate;
```

[JSFiddle of what I have so far of the code above](https://jsfiddle.net/gbc0h4Lk/)

Comment: When you say you didn't have any luck, what do you mean by that? What happened when you ran it?

Comment: @Nunchucks when I ran the code, it would return my main dish cost + the most recent value of the side dish i just added, not all of them. Let say I added Papadum (2) and Samosas (5), with the main dish lamb vindaloo (15), it would return 20. I want it to return 22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues in your code,

I will focus right now at the main issue - the calculate function -

You are iterating entries, and adding them up in a loop, and replacing value of innerHTML in a loop.

You should sum up all values, and the main dish, and update the html outside of the loop:

```
function calculate(){
    let sideValue = side.value;
    let sum = 0/1; //just so sum will be int.
    sideDishes.forEach(function(entry) {
        sum+=parseFloat(entry)
    });
    let mainValue = parseFloat(main.value);

    let add = sum + mainValue;
    document.getElementById("totalCost").innerHTML = add;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8w1mk9ze/